# Accessing Master View Controller from Detail View Controller inside Xcode Master-Detail Project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to create a little extension so I can access the Master View Controller from the Detail View Controller to update a variable.

```
import UIKit

extension UISplitViewController {

    var ggida_primaryViewController: UIViewController? {
        get {
            let navController = self.viewControllers.first! as? UINavigationController
            return navController.topViewController!
        }
    }

}
```

I call it using the following code:

```
let masterVC: MasterViewController? = self.splitViewController?.ggida_primaryViewController as! MasterViewController?
```

But get the following error:

```
Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' (0x10e2c2008) to 'xxx.MasterViewController' (0x10b980350).
```

Note this is in the Master-Detail project which due it's Navigation Controller is causing this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Some of it will depend on how you actually have your storyboard configured  to interact with the Navigation Controllers and the actual Master and Detail Controllers. Apple recommends [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uisplitviewcontroller) to "install primary and secondary view controllers that do not change. A common technique is to install navigation controllers in both [Master and Detail] positions and then push and pop new content as needed."

Using a brand new Master-Detail Application in Xcode 8.2 (which follows that pattern), this extension works for me:

```
extension UISplitViewController {
    var primaryViewController: MasterViewController? {
        let navController = self.viewControllers.first as? UINavigationController
        return navController?.topViewController as? MasterViewController
    }
}
```

Here is how I invoke it in `viewDidLoad()` in the DetailViewController:

```
let masterViewController = splitViewController?.primaryViewController
print(masterViewController?.objects)
```

In this case, the property `var objects = [Any]()` on the MasterViewController prints out correctly each time the DetailViewController loads.